# Javascript - Why are "function constructors" called "function constructors"?

Tags: javascript, constructor

My instructor is talking about function constructors ...

```
var neighbor = new Person()
```

and it raises a question for me that has plagued me since I started learning Javascript:

*Why are they called "function constructors?"*  After all, they don't construct functions; they construct objects. Why not "object constructors"?

I understand they are functions that "construct", and perhaps that is where the name comes from, but I still find the name very confusing.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I'd call that a "constructor function", not a "function constructor".  I don't recall ever hearing the latter term used.

Comment: That's not a function constructor. This is a function constructor: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function Just because its on Udemy doesn't mean the person who wrote the course is worth learning from. Anyway, you seem very hung up on terminology. What its called when you instantiate an object with `new` doesn't matter at all. What matters is how it works and how its used. Your energy would be much better spent building things that work instead of trying to figure out what some word means.

Comment: The term is actually used at the top of this documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function.   I think I am beginning to understand, though.  It's a function with the name "constructor". As in, "meet my new function, Constructor." Maybe?

Comment: I hadn't heard the term before (which of course doesn't mean anything). I can only speculate that means that constructors in legacy JavaScript take the form of regular functions, unlike other languages where they necessarily need to be inside classes and have a specific name.

Comment: @RyanScharfer no, that's a reference to the _constructor (function)_ of the class that's actually named `Function`.

Comment: @RyanScharfer - That's because that page explains the constructor of the `Function` object. If you read docs for `RegExp` it'll say "RegExp constructor".

Answer (score 1):

They are called [constructor functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_a_constructor_function) because they can be used to create an instance of an object when used with `new`.

> **Using a constructor function**
>
> - Define the object type by writing a constructor function. There is a    strong convention, with good reason, to use a capital initial
>     letter.
> - Create an instance of the object with new.

Answer (score 0):

In typed and "strong" object languages (like Java, C++ or C#), constructors, functions and method are very differents things and they clearly don't act the the same.

But javascript is not strongly typed. For javascript, a constructor is just a basic function and nothing else more. You can call a function without the `new` keyword, and if your function does not use the keyword `this`, it will return you an object (but probably empty).

So it is called "constructor function" because this is a function, but we (the coder) use it as a constructor.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure to be completely right. When you use `new` operator, you actually construct a new Object. And if you run `console.log(neighbor.constructor)`, you will see it prints `Person` function code.